# possible results of integral along closed path after defining branch of sqrt

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, branch-cuts

Prove that one can define a branch of the function $\sqrt{1-z^2}$ in every region $D\subset \mathbb{C}$ such that the points $-1$ and 1 belong to the same connected component of the complement of $D.$
How many values can the integral
$$\int_\gamma \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\sqrt{1-z^2}}$$
take along a closed path $\gamma$ contained in $D$ ?